# Как из String сделать &str (возникает ошибка времени жизни ссылки)

Tags: rust

Написал функцию:

```
fn read_str<'a>() -> &'a str {
    let mut input = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut input).ok();
    let output : &str = &input[..];
    &output
}
```

При компиляции возникает ошибка

```
src/main.rs:13:26: 13:31 error: `input` does not live long enough
src/main.rs:13     let output : &str = &input[..];
                                        ^~~~~
src/main.rs:10:30: 15:2 note: reference must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the block at 10:29...
src/main.rs:10 fn read_str<'a>() -> &'a str {
src/main.rs:11  let mut input = String::new();
src/main.rs:12  io::stdin().read_line(&mut input).ok();
src/main.rs:13     let output : &str = &input[..];
src/main.rs:14     &output
src/main.rs:15 }
src/main.rs:11:32: 15:2 note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the block suffix following statement 0 at 11:31
src/main.rs:11  let mut input = String::new();
src/main.rs:12  io::stdin().read_line(&mut input).ok();
src/main.rs:13     let output : &str = &input[..];
src/main.rs:14     &output
src/main.rs:15 }
```

Пробовал брать строку `io::stdin().read_line(&mut input).ok();` в фигурные скобки, дабы ограничить &mut, но это не помогает.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вернуть из функции можно только ссылку на статический объект (с временем жизни `'static`) или ссылку, которую вы получили во входных параметрах.

Вы пытаетесь вернуть ссылку на объект созданный в стеке функции. После завершения функции все объекты в стеке будут уничтожены. Rust не позволит создать ссылку на объект, который она может пережить. [Использование после освобождения (use after free)](http://kgv.github.io/rust_book_ru/src/references-and-borrowing.html#%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-use-after-free)

В вашем случае лучше всего вернуть `String`. Накладные расходы в этом случае невелики, так как почти вся информация внутри строки хранится в куче.

---

Большинство проблем начинающих писать на Rust связаны с непониманием назначения различных типов указателей. Если не вдаваться в подробности, их там можно насчитать пять штук.

Ссылки в Rust используются для передачи данных без передачи права владения.
Например если у вас есть структура, в которой хранится строка:

```
struct Person{
    name:String
}
```

то выдавать информацию о ее содержимом лучше так:

```
impl Person{
   pub fn get_name(&self)->&str{
      &self.name
   }
}
```

или можно вернуть копию строки:

```
pub fn get_name_clone(&self)->String{
    self.name.clone()
}
```

Но это приведет к дополнительным расходам на копирование строки. Расходы здесь возникают именно из-за копирования - вызова метода `clone()`, который создает вторую копию данных строки в куче, а не из-за того, что функция возвращает строку.

Можно вернуть строку из структуры без копирования:

```
pub fn get_name_own(self)->String{
    self.name
}
```

Но после вызова этого метода исходный объект `Person` перестанет существовать, так как право владения было передано.

Еще одна распространенная причина проблем - попытка хранить ссылки на другие объекты в структуре. Ссылки накладывают кучу ограничений на время жизни и мутабельность связанных объектов. Прежде чем это делать, стоит дважды подумать о возможности использования других типов указателей.

Comment: Спасибо вам за столь развёрнутый ответ, для меня главным стало упущение факта о невозможности вывода из функции не-static ссылки, непривычно после c++. Ресурсов русскоязычных по rust мало, надеюсь, что этот пост многим будет полезен.